# How to change number of shards in ElasticSearch Hibernate integration

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, sharding

I am using the hibernate elasticsearch integration (5.10.3) to move my index out of the application to an ES cluster. I want to reduce the amount of primary shards from 5 to 1, however I can't find any reference how to do this in the documentation.

Does anyone know how I can change the amount of shards?

Answer (score 0):

In Elastic Search, once the index is created you can't change the mapping type and setting that includes a number of shards as well as a replica. But you can reindex the existing index to the newly created index with your desired number of shards and replica. 
You can create a new Index Like this. For Example I have added a Mapping ingore if you want

```
PUT testing
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mappingExample": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you do a Reindex of the

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "yourindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "testing"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the Hibernate Search integration, as I believe that is limited to using the hibernate.properties file.